# Ignore last zeros after . with set format in Gnuplot

Tags: plot, floating-point, gnuplot

I use:

**set format x set format x "%2.3f"**

so that (for example) number 10.55555555 comes out as 10.555.

But at the same time, I would like that (for example) number 10.000000 comes out as 10, not as 10.000.

Is that possible? To tell gnuplot to use **set format x set format x "%2.3f"** but to ignore zeros?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think one can achieve this solely with `set format`. However, you could redefine the tic corresponding to position `10`. For example:

```
set xr [0:20]
set format x "%.3f"
set xtics add ("10" 10)
plot x
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for help, but it is not the solution to my problem. In practice I have many numbers and I would like for it to show decimals only when they are not .0000

Comment: then you could try to experiment with `"%.3g"` although that will strip trailing zeros also in other cases such as `0.25` vs. `0.250`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I want to eliminate zero whenever it is last digit. (Although for "%.3g" this option leaves 4 digits in some cases, it definitely eliminates "last" zeroes everywhere!)

Comment: I cannot "thump up" your comment, if you write it as an answer maybe I can give you green arrow! :)